# Select statement from a table, with no joins or filters running long. How to optimise

Tags: oracle, optimization, indexing, plsql

Trying to optimize a select statement from a global temporary table, no joins.
I tried indexing on all columns being selected and an operating hint.
Dropped the index and just created a primary key index and used in operating hint.No luck with both. Please suggest ..

```
SELECT  /*+ INDEX(fim_mp_po_lcm_gt_tst,PK_PO_HEADER_ID_TST) */
fmpl.operating_unit "Business Unit",
fmpl.period_name "Period Name",
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  "Report Date/Time" ,
fmpl.po_number "PO Number",
fmpl.po_brand "Brand",
fmpl.po_channel "Channel",
fmpl.dest_country "Destination",
fmpl.po_status "PO Status",
fmpl.currency_code "Currency",
TO_CHAR(fmpl.elc_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY') "ELC Date",
fmpl.elc_amt "Current Period ELC",
fmpl.alc_amt "Current Period ALC",
fmpl.variance_Amt "Variance Booked"
FROM FIM_MP_PO_LCM_GT_TST fmpl
```

Clearly the index is not being used

```
SQLQuery:EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'dm_plan_Q_210604_114114' FOR 
SELECT 
fmpl.operating_unit "Business Unit",
fmpl.period_name "Period Name",
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  "Report Date/Time" ,
fmpl.po_number "PO Number",
fmpl.po_brand "Brand",
fmpl.po_channel "Channel",
fmpl.dest_country "Destination",
fmpl.po_status "PO Status",
fmpl.currency_code "Currency",
TO_CHAR(fmpl.elc_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY') "ELC Date",
fmpl.elc_amt "Current Period ELC",
fmpl.alc_amt "Current Period ALC",
fmpl.variance_Amt "Variance Booked"

FROM "FIM_MP_PO_LCM_GT_TST" fmpl
SQL Query Timeout: 600
Number of SQL Executions: 1
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1118455586
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                      |     1 |   454 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| FIM_MP_PO_LCM_GT_TST |     1 |   454 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you're selecting the whole table with no joins or filters, full table scan is the fastest, don't try to use indices.

Comment: But clearly its taking a long time and then gets timed out after 3 hours,(Running this from BI publisher Data model) While the insert statement that populates the table takes around 15 mins.

Comment: That sounds like the problem is on the BI Publisher side, not with the table or data?

Comment: Could be..But for a smaller set of data, its just returning values in a few seconds..

Comment: Even more reason to suspect the BI Publisher side; have you tried executing your query directly on the server hosting the database?  I've seen plenty of times it was network / application setup that slowed things down.  Time to isolate where the slowness is happening.  If you [edit] your question with some more details such as "Query that returns 1,000 rows takes 23 seconds via BI Publisher, and 1.2 second via SQL*Plus, and query that returns 100,000 rows take 3.3 hours in BI and 3.3 minutes in SQL*PLus"

Comment: Thanks @MarkStewart for rightly pointing out..5 tried executing the query in DB directly using sql developer and it completed in less than 1 second for 17k records, where as more than 3 hours in BIP

Answer (score 0):

You can use PARALLEL hint on your query

the basic examle:

> SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(emp,4) */ COUNT(*)  FROM emp;

Comment: That would help if the parallel option was licensed.  But your example is a little different from the original question in that the example is returning one row, the `count(*)` of all rows in the table.  In that particular query an index could (also) be used to improve performance.  The index option would likely be better than parallel for that example.

Answer (score 0):

Using information from the comments, it appears that the query via the BI publisher data model was the cause of the long query run time, as Alex suspected.  And Mat correctly pointed out that if you need all the rows in the table for your query, no index would help.

This is one of the first things to check if a query is running slow, when running via some software package, such as BI Publisher:  Try running the query directly on the server (if possible) via a program such as SQL*Plus or SQL Developer.  That would eliminate the possibility of (most) network overhead or due to a client software configuration, etc.

Even if you have to run the query via SQL*Plus over the network instead of directly on the server, you can use the SQL*Plus command `set autotrace traceonly` to run the query, but not return the thousands/millions of rows across the network.

This approach helped prove the cause of the Original Poster's issue, as the OP noted in a comment, copying here for easy reference:

> query in DB directly using sql developer and it completed in less than 1 second for 17k records, where as more than 3 hours in BIP

Once I had to deal with an application that was very slow for most queries; it wasn't the software, nor the database, but it was the communications layer software, IBM's MQ message queuing software, that was configured to send a "keep awake" packet every few *seconds*, and it's keep awake packet was around 1,500 bytes, when maybe 100 bytes every few *minutes* would work. So hundreds of users, all those extra packets, on a 56 kilobyte network link (yeah, long time ago) was to blame.